# An object of a base class can’t be referred to using a reference variable of its derived class

Tags: java, oop

I was reading Object Oriented Programming's concepts from an OCA book. Here in Inheritance Chapter I saw this line written,

**An object of a base class can’t be referred to using a reference variable of its
derived class.**

But I am not able to get the meaning of it.

Comment: It means a Cat is an Animal, but an Animal is not necessarily a Cat.

Comment: Ah.. I got it now. Thanks @Kayaman